# How to achieve the same thing as LD_LIBRARY_PATH in cmake?

Tags: cmake

I am using CMakeLists.txt to handle a so file.
But I get an `error while loading shared libraries:`.
This error can be solved by setting `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`.
I want to know why `link_directories()`  in CMakeLists.txt cannot solve the problem?
What is the difference between `link_directories()` and `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`?

Comment: For understand LD_LIBRARY_PATH and related things you may read that article: https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/community/-/wikis/doc/cmake/RPATH-handling

Comment: The `link_directories()` setting controls the set of directories to search at _link time_.  `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` controls the set of directories to search at _run time_.  These are most of the time NOT the same directories, since at run time you've often installed the shared libraries into other locations.  You can set the default directories to search at run time as well, so you don't have to use `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, but it requires a separate setting.  See the CMake docs as Tsyvarev suggests.

Comment: Don't use `link_directories`, anyway. Create imported targets and link to those via `target_link_libraries`.